# Assign values to Tuple with named values in inline function

Tags: vb.net, tuples, .net-4.5

I'm supporting a solution using VS 2022 and Framework 4.5.2.

I'm trying to create a tuple with named values inside an inline function and pass it to another function.

I know how to declare the tuple inline without named parameters and assign values, and I know how to declare it inline with named values but not assign the values.

How do I do both?

The following is ok:

```
Dim q1 =
    myEnumerable.Select(
        Function(x) New Tuple(Of String, String, String)(x.Name, x.URL, x.Name)
    )
```

But this is not: (I get red squigglies under the values)

```
Dim q2 =
    myEnumerable.Select(
        Function(x) New Tuple(Of (name As String, link As String, tooltip As String))(x.Name, x.URL, x.Name)
    )
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Why is this tagged .NET 4.8 yet you say .NET Framework 4.5.2 in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax will work in one line to produce the named tuple you want

```vb
Dim q2 = myEnumerable.Select(Function(x) (Name:=x.Name, URL:=x.URL, tooltip:=x.Name))
```

Or using inferred names for the first 2

```vb
Dim q2 = myEnumerable.Select(Function(x) (x.Name, x.URL, tooltip:=x.Name))
```

Comment: Thanks - just trying to work out whether I prefer yours or mine. Yours is snappier, mine more explicit.

Comment: There's implicit typing in constructing the Tuple here, for example if you change the type of the URL to a [Url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.policy.url?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), you don't need to modify this code. Yours is perfectly fine too, my first time seeing it

Comment: Your is better. Mine is actually wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out in the end. I just needed more brackets:

```
Dim q3 =
    myEnumerable.Select(
        Function(x) New Tuple(Of (name As String, link As String, tooltip As String))((x.Name, x.URL, x.Name))
    )
```